# More elegant alternative for "value === false"?

Tags: javascript, coding-style, comparison, boolean

In JavaScript, I want to compare a value for (strict) equality to `false`.

From Java / C# I am used to writing:

```
if (!value)
   //Do Something
```

However, I can not use it in JavaScript as `null`, `undefined` (and others IMHO) evaluate to `false` inside an if-statement, too. (I don't want that).

Thus, I have therefore been writing the following to formulate such a check:

```
if (value === false)
   //Do Something
```

Yet, this construct looks a little bit strange to me.
Are there any more elegant ways here (which lead to the same results as the `=== false` of course)?

Introducing a method `isFalse` would be an option, of course, but that's not what I am looking for as it would look even more distracting than the `=== false`.

Comment: Sadly, lots of things in JavaScript look strange to those of us accustomed to real languages. :)

Comment: Probably stick with `=== false` ... or switch it around to `false === ...`

Comment: `if(!value)` is going to slap you in your face if `value` is not an actually boolean in those languages you mentioned. Very annoying if you are working with bitmasks where "0 = false, everything else = true" would save you some typing. anyway, be happy that you don't need `a.equals(b)` but can use `a === b` instead of complaining about a perfectly fine construct that is not strange ;)

Comment: The question is whether you really have to distinguish between `false` and e.g. `null`. if you think you have to, why? What should happen if `value` is `null`?

Comment: For optional arguments it make sense to test `=== false` and `=== true` since a not-set argument is `undefined`

Comment: @ThiefMaster: Of course, but we don't know the context.

Comment: @Felix Kling: The context actually is an optional argument which should not have "false" as its default value.

Comment: @winSharp93: What are the other possible values? Is `null` a valid value?

Comment: @Felix Kling: True and false are both valid, undefined has same effect as true; an exception is thrown when null is passed as null is invalid.

Comment: @winSharp93: You might be better off just testing for `undefined` and accept anything boolish otherwise: `if (arg === undefined || arg)`.

Comment: @Ferdinand Beyer: Thanks, definitely an alternative to consider.

Comment: `if(arg === undefined) arg = true;` would be better IMO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please, don't write a function `isFalse()` (a candidate for [The Daily WTF](http://thedailywtf.com)), use the `===` operator even if it looks strange to you, there is no cleaner way.

Comment: Don't worry, I am not going to do that - as said, isFalse(value) "would look even more distracting" ;-)

Answer (score 7):

If you truly want to check for an explicit `false` value in Javascript, as opposed to a 'falsy' value (`null`, `undefined`, `0`, etc.) then `=== false` is by far the most standard way of doing so. I don't think it needs to be changed - that's part of the beauty of such a dynamic language!